# Selecting all Rows Between Two Dates with Dynamic MAX(date)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with `user_id` `timestamp` and other characteristics. I'm trying to select all the rows which contain the users last time stamp in addition to the last 90 day before that. Since a users last `timestamp` is different for each user I can't simply include a `BETWEEN` condition with two fixed dates.

I've attempted the variations of the following with no luck

```
SELECT  mt.user_id, mt.date_logged AS dates
FROM members_table AS mt
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, mt.date_logged, MAX(mt.date_logged)) < 90
```

Comment: What happens with the query you tried?

Comment: It gives the following error: `SQL Error[1582][42000]: incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'`

Comment: I'd say it's quite obvious why it's not working then. You have too many parameters. Use a combination of DATEPART and TO_DAYS maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an aggregation function in the `WHERE` clause, since aggregation happens *after* selecting the rows. You need to join with a subquery that returns the max for each user.

```
SELECT mt.user_id, mt.date_logged AS dates
FROM members_table AS mt
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, DATE_SUB(MAX(date_logged), INTERVAL 90 DAY) AS startdate
    FROM members_table
    GROUP BY user_id) AS mx
ON mt.user_id = mx.user_id AND mt.date_logged > mx.start_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT mt.user_id, mt.date_logged AS dates
FROM
(SELECT  
  user_id, 
  max(date_logged) AS max_dts, 
  dateadd(max(date_logged), interval -90 day) last90_dts
FROM 
  members_table
GROUP BY user_id) der
join members_table AS mt ON mt.user_id=der.user_id and mt.date_logged between last90_dts and max_dts;
```

Derived table: Created to have a list per userwise min and max date range
Self join: Self joined when we have range for each user.

Thanks